Validating schema has one of several props in the object
I am using Zod to validate my schema, but one particular part of the object I am expecting can have one of three different key/values.
For example:
{
  results: {
    // I'll only ever receive one of these resultTypes at a time
    resultType1: { onlyInOne: 'blah', ... },
    resultType2: { onlyInTwo: 'blah', ... },
    resultType3: { onlyInThree: 'blah', ... },
    ...
  }
}

So results will only contain one of the different resultTypeX props.
Currently I have added optional to each of the types, but that leaves me open to validating true an object that has a results object with none of those three, when I want to specify that I have exactly one of them.
const resultType1 = z.object({ onlyInOne: z.string(), ... });
const resultType2 = z.object({ onlyInTwo: z.string(), ... });
const resultType3 = z.object({ onlyInThree: z.string(), ... });

const schema = z.object({
  results: z.object({
    resultType1: resultType1.optional(),
    resultType2: resultType2.optional(),
    resultType3: resultType3.optional()
  })
});


I know there is the required attribute, but I'm not entirely sure that it is valid here to do what I'm wanting?
Is there a way to make this specification? Could it be an Enum?

I think unions are what you're looking for. Enum is useful for strings, numbers, etc., but it don't work correctly with objects.

Zod includes a built-in z.union method for composing "OR" types.

const resultType1 = z.object({ ... });
const resultType2 = z.object({ ... });
const resultType3 = z.object({ ... });

const schema = z.object({
  results: z.union([
    z.object({ resultType1: resultType1 }),
    z.object({ resultType2: resultType2 }),
    z.object({ resultType3: resultType3 })
 ])
});


Zod will test the input against each of the "options" in order and
return the first value that validates successfully.

For convenience, you can also use the .or method:
 const stringOrNumber = z.string().or(z.number()); // string | number
 
 // equivalent to z.union([z.string(), z.number()]);

Discriminated unions can also be useful. They are a union of object schemas that all share a particular key.
const myUnion = z.discriminatedUnion("status", [
  z.object({ status: z.literal("success"), data: z.string() }),
  z.object({ status: z.literal("failed"), error: z.instanceof(Error) }),
]);

myUnion.parse({ status: "success", data: "yippie ki yay" });


Thanks for the extra bit of clarity on the different types. I think I'm still going to struggle though... The issue is that each of the 3 types that can be found will have different key names, so I don't think the discriminatedUnion will quite work

Your welcome, What about union?  Why it doesn't resolve your problem

I'm looking to see if I can make more sense of it. I've updated the question to add a little more real-life structure to the object expected etc. I just can't see how it would work without it still coming back to having multiple .optional() bits, defeating the purpose.

I think the issue comes from the fact that it's not just the value of a particular key that can be different, but it's both the key and value that are conditional.

I've update the answer with a better example of union, is it now works for the problem?

After trying it... It has the same effect as my original .optional() version, where you can validate against an object that contains multiple of the one, two, three examples.  I think I'm needing it to validate that it only has one of the three types
